# How to read variable contents instead of file path?

Tags: python, file, variables, path, stringio

I have a Python function [1] which requires the file path pointing to the file it has to process as an argument. However, I have a string variable containing the contents of the respective file. I don't want to create a file only to read it with said function and then delete the file.

Is there a way to pass a variable instead of a file path pointing to a file with the same contents?

Example of the problem:

```py
data = '1,2,3\n4,5,6'

# this is the intended function use:
process_data('data.csv')

# this is how I would like to use it 
# so that I don't have to create a file
process_data(data)
```

[1] Specifically, said function is `boto3.client.upload_file(file_path, bucket, target_path)`

I've read through some ways to use `io.StringIO` but somehow I'm unlucky to get them running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`boto3.client.upload_file`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_file) expects a filename and not a file object, hence why you cannot use `io.StringIO` with it. However you can use [`boto3.client.upload_fileobj`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_file), which precisely works with file objects, *eg.*

```python
import io
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

f = io.StringIO('1,2,3\n4,5,6')
s3.upload_fileobj(f, ...)
```

Comment: Oh boi. That was too easy, I guess. Thanks a lot!